How to easily build a class in Python using @dataclass, @property and showing no dunder parameters in the constructor?
Let's say that I want to start with this class, which is going to grow in functionality, so let's just throw in a few attributes and keep them "private", using the preceding dunder, and make use of the @property decorator to add some business logic there or simply keep a specific level of visibility, ending with something like this:
class Whatever:
    __attr1: int
    __attr2: str
    __attr3: list[str]

    @property
    def attr1(self) -> int:
       return self.__attr1

    @property
    def attr2(self) -> str:
        return self.__attr2

    @__attr2.setter
    def attr2(self, value: str) -> None:
        ...
        self.__attr2 = value

    def filtered_attr3(self, p1: str) -> list[str]:
        filtered: list[str]
        ...
        return filtered

What should I do regarding the constructor? I'd like to make something Pythonic to obtain the results I intend to get.
I read that it's recommended to use the @dataclass decorator to keep the process of building the __init__ method automated. But this comes with downsides: in the same way that I try to hide the attributes from outside the class, this decorator is going to take its name and show it as a constructor parameter. For such a case I read about backing fields, declaring the attributes duplicate, but without the "__" prefix and making use of the typing.field method with this sentence for every attribute:
...
attr1: int
__attr1 = field(init=False, repr=False)
...

But  if I want to spare myself the trouble of typing the __init__ method it's not to change it for a far worse boilerplate code. Otherwise I can't find any other alternatives that comply with all the points previously mentioned.
What would be considered better?

@dataclass + __attr + @property
@dataclass + attr (instead of __attr) + @property
__init__ + __attr + @property
Go the simple way with __init__ and dispose of everything else mentioned.
Any other alternative I didn't think of?

I think that that the best option could be using both annotations and dispose of the "private" attributes, since methods with @property decorator before them would trigger before letting access to the attributes directly, thus leaving the automatic constructor parameters underscore-free as well.

I think you're trying to get too clever by combining @dataclass and @property. They're working at cross purposes.

If __attr2 is "private" but you make a getter and setter for it, then what have you accomplished? Basically, you now have nothing but a proxy, and your "private" member is exposed in every way except actual name.

If you're willing to look beyond the dataclasses module and try pydantic, this all becomes much easier; see the docs for private model attributes. Any attributes with a leading underscore are considered private.

Just write the __init__. Also, you almost certainly don't want to use double-underscores, just use a single underscore. And that is only if you actually need to control access, if you are just going to use a property with a getter/setter that don't do any sort of logic, then just use a regular attribute with no leading underscore

"Go the simple way with __init__ and dispose of everything else mentioned." if this is an alternative, why are you even considering the others? that seems like then your property getters/setters don't do anything

@Barmar, that might be a mistake I'm making. However I don't understand why are they working at cross purposes. All I see is that whilst @dataclass is giving an interface to initialize the object, @property is setting a customized/-able interface to interact with the different attributes. I completely ignore why would they interfere with each other.

@OysterShucker, this is just an example, hence the ellipsis. Although it's true that I just assigned __attr2 the parameter value. There I just tried to explain that there might be more code doing stuff that has no relevance regarding the question. Excuse me for not being clear enough.

@juanpa.arrivillaga Answering to your first comment, thank you. I got that concept the other way around. You're also right, that if there's no logic implied, getters/setters are pretty much redundant.
Now answering to the second, I just consider this an alternative in case that the rest are just overcomplicating everything and the simplest would be recommended for whatever reason I ignore, although I have read the docs. I was simply asking for opinion and advice, don't get me wrong.

@larsks thanks for your suggestion. I gave it a brief look and it looks interesting. I'll read it more in detail and I may probably use it later in my project.

I consider it cross purposes because one of the main features of @dataclass is that the attributes are automatically turned into __init__() parameters, and you're trying to get around that. If you don't want what dataclasses do, you don't need to use them. They're just a shortcut for a common case, and your use doesn't really match that case.

Alright, now I get what you mean and you're right. I think that, to avoid the cross purposes that you talked about, I should better get rid of the underscores and rely, as the other mates said, on the default attributes and, in case of needing additional logic, make use of properties. Thank you for clarifying and your help to you all. Greetings. :)
